# Repeat CASE block with IF/ELSE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to generate a report from SQL Server Stored Procedure, where the condition is the same but the results are different for 10 columns.

I am using the CASE statement for this. Also there are IF/ELSE blocks within each CASE. This IF/ELSE block pulls data from different columns.

I am repeating the same CASE statement 10 times as following:

```
SELECT     
CASE WHEN table1.Field="aa"
THEN 
  select table2.Field
ELSE 
   select table3.Field
END  as 'FirstColumn',  

 CASE WHEN table1.Field="aa"

THEN 
   select table4.Field 
ELSE 
 table5.Field END as 'SecondColumn'
```

This way I had to repeat same the CASE statement 10 times. Could anybody suggest any better approach?

Comment: table1, table2, ... , tableN have the same schema?

Comment: Yes all have the same schema

Comment: Why don't you make some sort of lookup table you can `JOIN` in?

Comment: How I can do that? Can u give an example or shared some link?

Comment: Can you please show the whole query, especially the from clause

Answer (score 1):

According to your example the condition is the same for all the clauses :

```
table1.Field="aa"
```

If this assumption is correct, I would suggest a different approach to solving this problem.
Create 2 queries, one for each possibility and switch between them using the IF ELSE syntax.

Something like this:

```
DECLARE @Var varchar(2)
SELECT @Var = Field
FROM table1 IF @Var = 'aa' BEGIN
SELECT table2.Field AS 'FirstColumn',
       table4.Field AS 'SecondColumn'
FROM table2,
     table4 END 
ELSE BEGIN
SELECT table3.Field AS 'FirstColumn' ,
       table5.Field AS 'SecondColumn'
FROM table3,
     table5 END
```

You can find a working example on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c366e/12).

Let me know if I misunderstood something and I'll try to correct ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This may be more appropriate as a comment, but it is too long.

Your SQL doesn't make sense.  You have subqueries in the `when` clause with no parentheses, so this is not valid SQL.  In addition, you have double quotes around strings, which means the `"aa"` is interpreted as a column reference, not a constant.  And finally, you have single quotes around the column aliases, which although allowed, is bad practice.

I also don't know what you mean by "there are IF/ELSE blocks within each CASE", because that also is not allowed in SQL.

If you mean:

```
select (CASE WHEN table1.Field = 'aa' THEN table2.Field
             ELSE table3.Field
        END)  as FirstColumn,
       (CASE WHEN table1.Field = 'aa' then table4.Field 
             ELSE table5.Field
        END) as SecondColumn
```

Then `case` statement seems to capture your logic correctly.  Because `table1.field` could vary for each row (as opposed to being constant for the entire query), I don't see a way to "simplify" this.

However, I've made a bunch of assumptions.  You can should modify your question with a better example of the actual code.  Or delete this question and start over again with a better explanation.